# metal plate VS ferrite plate

Tags: wireless-charging

I'm designing a wireless charger project for our UV light cure system and don't want to buy a wireless module because they are not professional actually (using very simple components without any protection on the TX side) instead, I want to use full-bridge MOSFET arrangement on TX side and Litz wire in the coils.
So my question is because of the lack of thin ferrite plate in our market, I want to use a 2mm metal plate instead of ferrite in the back of the coils! what is your suggestion? Is it OK?

Comment: If it worked, they wouldn't be using ferrite plates.

Comment: You say "metal" -- do you mean copper, for its electrical characteristics?  Or do you mean iron, for its magnetic characteristics?  Ferrite is used because it has specific *magnetic* properties, and high bulk resistance.  You could maybe substitute laminated strips of iron (laminated to avoid eddy current losses), but by the time you were done you may find its easier to build a ferrite factory and start supplying ferrite to your market, or start importing ferrite, ditto.

Comment: @TimWescott  got it

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't work. Eddy current losses. It will act as a shorted turn.

Comment: You're right, it seems the only choice is Ferrite plate